# Problem connecting, socks failure

Tags: socks, censorship, connection

Recently I'm not able to connect anymore to Tor and other vpns through my provider who blocks access to them. I reinstalled Tor, got bridges from the email, but it still doesn't work.

The log says :

[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to ... ("general SOCKS server failure")

[NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges

I haven't set any SOCKS proxies, it could be that my provider does.

Comment: Tor does set a socks proxy on port 9050 for Tor and 9051 for Tor Browser. Can you please let us know which OS you are using an whether you are using Tor or TorBrowser?

Comment: @JSEvans I'm using Windows 10 and Tor browser.

I checked port 9051 and it's blocked. How can I unblock it, or change the port?